# Empty alert message TYPO3 Backend when edit filemount (sys_filemounts)

Tags: iis, typo3, alert, mount-point, fal

Today, I've made a Core-Update from `TYPO3 7.6.9`to `TYPO3 7.6.14`(latest 12/2016) on a Windows Server IIS. There were some database changes, mainly `sys_file_metadata`?!

Now it's impossible to add a new file mount.
I've already 20 different file mounts (`sys_filemounts`) before update, everything works fine. Now I can't select the folder, see image

I wrote the path into the database, but that also won't work.
Only the empty error alert box from TYPO3?! What can I do?

**EDIT: The filemount works. I've test it with an editor. So maybe it's a bug :`TYPO3 7.6.14`? What do you think?**

[image: edit filemount TYPO3]

Screenshot from database compare .. do I sth. wrong? I clicked execute ...

Thanks for your help .. I've no idea what's wrong.

[image: compare database]

Comment: Silly question, but did you check the checkboxes before clicking execute?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes sure. I checked all boxes and execute. See my `edit`. The file mount works. There must be a problem with TYPO3 ... stefan

Comment: I have another TYPO3 7.6.14-Installation, where I haven't execute the database compare. At this project, the file mounts still working. Is there sth. with these database tables `cf_extbase_typo3dbbackend_tablecolumsn ..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy Holidays!

There were some files with special characters like 'ä ü ö' etc. in `fileadmin/user_upload/...`. Some of the Editors upload these files via FTP, not via TYPO3-Filelist. Damn ;)

TYPO3 CMS upload change `Wrong FIle_2ä.pdf` to `wrong-file_2ae.pdf` automatically - FTP won't.

No bug!